# Please reopen my question

Tags: support

[On MacBooks, is there a difference between "Low battery" and "You are now running on reserve battery power"?](https://superuser.com/q/1522810/1136553)

I would like this question to be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.

As per the close reason.

> The reason why I ask this is because I am curious about how MacBooks work. I do not use a MacBook, but rather a Windows laptop. So please do not try to post "bug fix" answers thinking that I am having problems with my computer.

There's no actual problem to be solved

> [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I have re-edited my question.